# How to handle VirtualBox images from different account in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

In Windows7 I seem to have a problem with `VBoxManage` when I am trying to clone a virtual image. In the user's account it is no problem to run the command on the command prompt, but a different user cannot do so. The error message is:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonevm UbuntuTest --name TestNeu --register 
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'UbuntuTest'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(pszSrcName).raw(), srcMachine.asOutParam())" at line 434 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

Maybe I need to set an environment variable to tell where to look for the image? Or tell the command itself where to look for the image? What else can be done?

The command to list all virtual boxes

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" list vms
```

returns nothing.